# Rails search table column for a phrase

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have this so far:

```
@newevent = Event.find(params[:id])
ne = @newevent.url
@tm = Master.find_by(deep_link: ne)
```

What I want is the value from `ne` to be searched across the whole `Master table` column `deep_link`.

Then return everything back from the row that contains the url.

Comment: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> is the response i get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you, I believe that you need:

```
@newevent = Event.find(params[:id])
ne = @newevent.url
@tm = Master.where("deep_link LIKE ?", "%#{ne}%")
```

And then you need to loop throught the results in your view:

```
<% @tm.each do |result| %> 
    <%= result %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey there, For some reason it trys to include the % in the search, And also its onyl returnign one thing so the each isnt working..

Comment: Can you add more details what you need?

Comment: I did something different in the end, I did find_by rather than where, And i also did an = not a LIKE